# How to get source of twig block in twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have following twig block in template which extends main layout:

```
{% block abc %}
    {{ name }}
{% endblock %}
```

next I have a head block in the same template. I want to pass block abc as template for twig.js:

```
{% block head %}
<script type="text/html" id="template-abc">
     {{ blocksource('abc') }}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

so the rendering result is:
    
         {{name}}

How can I do this?

I tried building "blocksource" function in twig extension, but I don't know how to access block source form here.

```
function blocksource( Twig_Environment $env, $blockname) {
    $source = ???;
    return $source;
}
```

Comment: So you want the raw value of the `abc` block? In other words, you don't want Twig to interpret `{{ name }}`?

Comment: yes, I want to use same template in symfony2 twig template and also in client side using javascript and twig.js

Answer (score -1):

Use verbatim tag, it will do what you want.

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{ things_you_want_to_show_as_twig_template }}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Everything inside this tag will not be interpreted by twig engine.

You can read more on that in [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html).

Comment: if I use verbatim, how can I render this block in server side twig template?

Comment: Twig template, in general, is just a string with special tags. Render that string with twig engine. Here is example from twig docs: 
$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('Hello {{ name }}!', array('name' => 'Fabien'));

Comment: you wrote a php example. But verbatim block will be located in twig template. How do I render it in twig, not in php.
So basically I need one twig block to be outputted as plain twig source and rendered as twig template.

Comment: verbatim tag is used to skip processing text located inside. So you can put there anything. Now for rendering some context inside template you could try to create twig function [http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_SimpleFunction.html](Twig_SimpleFunction) Or alternatively you could try to use twig render() function with some controller where you can pass parameters

Comment: How can I access verbatim block data in twig function?